# Equation for Covariance of 2 Operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, covariance

In quantum mechanics, we can find a theoretical variance of operator $A$ with $\langle A^2\rangle-\langle A\rangle ^2$.

Is there a similar equation for the covariance of two operators $A$ and $B$? Does this question even make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing with the covariance in "regular" stochastics, where it can be caclulated as $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)=\mu(XY)-\mu(X)\mu(Y)$, where $\mu$ is the expectation value and $X,Y$ are random variables, you could try something like $\langle AB\rangle-\langle A\rangle \langle B\rangle$ where $A,B$ are two hermetian operators (i.e. correspond to observables of the system).

But this is not always useful in my opinion, because in quantum mechanics the measurement of one observable might influence the measurement of the other one, i.e. you cannot measure both "at the same time" like with classical variables. So we could restric ourselves to the case where $[A,B]=0$, i.e. both operators commute. This means every state $\vert \Psi\rangle$ can be expanded in simultaneous eigenstates $\vert a,b\rangle$, where $A\vert a,b\rangle=a\vert a,b\rangle$ and $B\vert a,b\rangle=b\vert a,b\rangle$. This expansion (in the case of non-degenerate eigenvalues, but the degenerate case is analogous) would look like
$$ \vert \Psi\rangle=\sum_{a,b} c_{a,b} \vert a,b\rangle$$
where $\vert c_{a,b}\vert^2=P(A=a,B=b)$ is the probability to measure the eigenvalue $a$ for $A$ and $b$ for $B$. Now plug that general state into $\langle AB\rangle-\langle A\rangle \langle B\rangle$ and you get:
$$\langle AB\rangle-\langle A\rangle \langle B\rangle=\sum_{a,b} P(A=a,B=b) ab -\left(\sum_{a} P(A=a) a \right)\left(\sum_{b} P(B=b) b \right) $$
which exactly what one would call $\mathrm{Cov}(A,B)$. (I used $P(A=a)=\sum_{b} P(A=a,B=b)$ and $P(B=b)=\sum_{a} P(A=a,B=b)$).

Now I said that we have that $\langle AB\rangle-\langle A\rangle \langle B\rangle$ is the covariance wenn $A$ and $B$ commute, but that does not mean that it is completely useless when they don't commute. It just might have a different interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:$$\begin{align}\operatorname{Cov}(A,\,B)&=\frac14\sum_\pm\pm\operatorname{Var}(A\pm B)\\&=\frac14\sum_\pm\pm[\langle(A\pm B)^2\rangle-\langle A\pm B\rangle^2]\\&=\frac14\sum_\pm\pm[\langle A^2+B^2\rangle\pm\langle AB+BA\rangle-\langle A\rangle^2-\langle B\rangle^2\mp2\langle A\rangle\langle B\rangle]\\&=\frac12\langle AB+BA\rangle-\langle A\rangle\langle B\rangle.\end{align}$$